# Excel: Count how many last days of the month are between & including two dates - datedif isn't consistent

Tags: excel-formula

I need to be able to count how many last days of the month there are between & including two dates:
e.g. 31/08/2021 to 15/10/2021 would be two (August and September).

31/08/2021 to 31/10/2021 would be three (August, September, October).

I've tried datedif+1, using months as the counting unit, but it isn't consistent, If the second date is the end of a month it will only count that month if its one that has a 31st in it.

31/08/2021 to 30/09/2021 = 1 (should be 2)

31/08/2021 to 31/10/2021 = 3 (correct)

30/08/2021 to 30/11/2021 = 3 (should be 4)

30/08/2021 to 31/12/2021 = 5 (correct)

Can anyone think of another way?

Comment: If you increase the last date by one day, you should get the right result. (btw: always good to have sample code)

Comment: Thank you - I should have put the code in completely rather than explaining it. Unfortunately increasing the last date results in an incorrect result where the last date is the second to last day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious and found this link: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-months-between-dates - it explains that DATEDIF works with whole months only - the suggestion to add 15 days to the end date doesn't work for your case.

But subtracting 16 days from start date and adding 16 days to end date results in the diff you want.

Furthermore the formula first calculates the end date: if it is not an "end of month", previous end of month will be calculated.

```
=LET(trueEOM,IF(B2=EOMONTH(B2,0),B2,EOMONTH(B2,-1)),
DATEDIF(A2-16,trueEOM+16,"m"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works for those examples, but doesn't work if the end date is the day before the end of the month. If you change 31/10/2021 to 30/20/2021 it still returns 3, but I need a count of 2 (Aug, Sep). I should have given more examples to show I am not only working with dates that are the end of the month, but it was the easiest way to illustrate the problem.

Comment: do you have Excel 365?

Comment: Yes - Excel 365.

Comment: Ok - now I am checking for the "true end of month".